# Mirth Connect HTTP Listener Mapping Response ACK message

Tags: hl7, mirth

We are trying to merge two Mirth servers. One server (let's call it Server 1) is keeping all records and another server (Server 2) is getting HL7 message from the first one and writes messages to the database.

Everything was perfect so far. But Server 1, after sending each HL7 message, waits for ACK to consider this transaction as completed and to send another message from the list.

The success status coming from the Server 2 (which writes to the database) contains MySQL response such as "*Success: Database write success. 1 rows updated.*". This is not what Server 1 is expecting.

Therefore, the Server 1 considers this ACK as invalid, produces an error "*Message Read Error - Will Retry*" and keeps trying to send the same message again, causing Server 2 to duplicate messages in the database.

We are using Mirth Connect HTTP listener and we could not find any solution to send ACK msg to our first server the same screen HTTP listener.

Is there any way to do this? Any Suggestion?

Really need help.

Comment: Your description of this issue is challenging to read. Let me get this straight: you have Mirth Connect on one server, and MySQL on another server? Mirth Connect is sending the hl7 to the mysql server? You say you are trying to "merge" two servers - do you mean that you are trying to "integrate" two servers or "consolidate" two servers into one?

Comment: Hi csj,
We fixed it. We used javascript writer and ACK map. Problem was ACK message that we are sending.
I will post here full detail that other people can use it

Comment: I would be interested in seeing that full detail. I honestly have almost no idea what your problem or solution were.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not setting the response from server 2 correctly, so it just returns what the destination has. You can create an ACK by code on the destination transformer:

```
var ackMessage = ACKGenerator.generateAckResponse(connectorMessage.getRawData(), "AA", "Message Successfully Received");
responseMap.put("ackresp", ResponseFactory.getSentResponse(ackMessage));
```

And on your source connector select "ackresp" as response. Your server 1 will receive that ACK instead of the log of the database write.